# La API URL que estoy consumiendo tiene protocolo HTTP y no funciona en productivo

Tags: api, http, https, xmlhttprequest

Estoy consumiendo la API **http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/** y funciona a la perfección en el ambiente de desarrollo, pero cuando hago el deploy e ingreso al link que Netlify me provee, obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://monumental-banoffee-379a6e.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

La cuestión es que si aggrego el http**S**//challenge-react.alkemy.org/  a la API URL, el link se rompe y no funciona (evidentemente la API funciona únicamente con el protocolo http. Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? Es posible?

En varios foros encontré que una solución es agregar una meta tag al HTML como la siguiente, pero aún asi no me funciona:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />`

Comment: Sí. Es decir: si el navegador del usuario carga directamente esa URL del otro sitio, el navegador valida que no cargues cosas sobre HTTP y HTTPS en una misma página, eso es inseguro y una mala práctica. Ahora, si el otro sitio no tiene servicio sobre HTTPS, tienes que indicarle al navegador que relaje el pony y no valide la seguridá de forma estricta. De nuevo, la buena práctica es no mezclar contenidos...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Alfabravo! Y como le indico al navegador que no valide estrictamente de forma segura? Aunque no sea una buena práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicación: Si el navegador del usuario carga directamente esa URL del otro sitio, el navegador valida que no cargues cosas sobre HTTP y HTTPS en una misma página, eso es inseguro y una mala práctica puesto que un atacante puede suministrar contenidos por HTTP y usar la sesión segura.

Ahora, si el otro sitio no tiene servicio sobre HTTPS, tienes que indicarle al navegador que relaje el pony y no valide la seguridá de forma estricta. De nuevo, la buena práctica es no mezclar contenidos.

Yo por ahora sólo he visto que debe hacerse en la configuración del navegador (nada en el contenido de la página deshabilita esto, porque entonces el atacante podría enviar esta indicación desde el contenido HTTP injectado). Ya sea para una página específica (como explican en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434461/236345)).

Ya sea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ó

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra es ir a la configuración general del navegador (about:config, Chrome://net-internals, cosas así) y desactivar la validación :/

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo! Permitiendo el contenido inseguro de mi app especifica como describiste en los prints pude solucionarlo. Entiendo que no es una buena practica y el protocolo a usarse deberia ser HTTPS, pero la API ya viene con ese protocolo y a fines de practica no tengo otro remedio que utilizarlo como viene, je!